# Wrong URL Address produced?

Tags: asp.net, html

I'm using a true URL address in my `<a>` tags but when run my project produced a wrong URL address!Why?
This is codes:

```
<ul id="accordion">
 <li>
     <div> صفحه اصلی</div>
     <ul>
         <li><a href="Default.aspx">بازگشت به صفحه اصلی</a></li>
     </ul>
 </li>
 <li>
     <div>عملیات مربوط به واحدها</div>
     <ul>
         <li><a href="Units/Reports/SelledUnitReport.aspx">گزارش واحدهای فروخته شده</a></li>
         <li><a href="Units/Reports/BlockedUnitReport.aspx">گزارش واحدهای بلوکه شده</a></li>
         <li><a href="Units/Reports/ReservedUnitReport.aspx">گزارش واحدهای رزرو شده</a></li>
         <li><a href="Units/Reports/FreeUnitReport.aspx">گزارش واحدهای قابل فروش</a></li>
         <li><a href="Units/UnitStateForm.aspx">تعیین وضعیت یک واحد</a></li>
     </ul> 
...
```

And when run the page I saw a wonder URL !
[image]

Can you tell me why happen this problem?

Comment: @mahditahsildari you can zoom your browser!do you understand???

Comment: @mahditahsildari Please right click the image and click view image. No need of zooming i think. As i can see it clear this way.

Comment: I think you have got right answer by Weacked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a relative URL, which the browser resolves *relative* to the current page URL.

You want to use an absolute URL, starting with `/`.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the pages you are trying to open through links and your default.aspx page are in the same directory (reports directory), so it is wrong to give folder names, just give the page names as

```
 <ul>
     <li><a href="SelledUnitReport.aspx">گزارش واحدهای فروخته شده</a></li>
     <li><a href="BlockedUnitReport.aspx">گزارش واحدهای بلوکه شده</a></li>
     <li><a href="ReservedUnitReport.aspx">گزارش واحدهای رزرو شده</a></li>
     <li><a href="FreeUnitReport.aspx">گزارش واحدهای قابل فروش</a></li>
     <li><a href="UnitStateForm.aspx">تعیین وضعیت یک واحد</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: I do this and this solution just solve this '<ul>' tag.in other '<ul>' tags produced "http://localhost:54474/Units/Reports/" !
these tags exist in different folders

Answer (score 0):

You are already in the Folder Units/Reports and try to go to the subfolder again.

It is a relative URL.

Maybe just remove the name of the subfolders?
Or use absolute URLs.